# how to connect SQL Azure using local ssms?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

This may be a duplicate question, but i tried all way to connect the SQL Azure database from my local SSMS.

I have created Azure database in cloud and added my system IP in firewall  configuration section, As I am on being corporate network and trying to connect azure database from my local ssms then i am getting below error,

"A network-Related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your IP in Azure as an allowed IP address. 
Go to your database in the Azure portal, select configure -> Add to the allowed ip addresses.

Then connect to < Database name >.database.windows.net

Comment: I already tried with adding my IP address, but still i am not able to connect. also i am on being corporate network, i am suspecting it is related with network issue.